# Stuck with a simple code

Tags: python, python-3.x, boolean-expression

So i have this code:

```
print("immutable"[-5:][:3]==9)
```

(i'm pretty new to coding in python 3 and i understand what my code is suppoused to do or rather what i'm trying to do which is to count the lengt of the word "immutable")

But what i can't figure out is how or rather why the output is "False".

I've even tried messing around with that code taking in len(9), or ==[9], changing the number etc. those times i gotten an error i understod why but i just can't get my head around why i get "False", the reason i can't wrap my head around it might as well just be because of me staring myself blind at this code but i would like any kinds of help i can get since right now i'm stuck.

Comment: you're missing `len("immutable")`. Comparing strings to integers is always false.

Comment: `len("immutable")==9` => `True`. Now play with the slicing

Comment: Check print("immutable"[-5:]) then print("immutable"[-5:][:3]) and so on

Comment: `immutable"[-5:][:3]` returns a string and you are comparing it with an integer. You always get `False`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is [`len()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#len):

```
print(len("immutable") == 9)
```

which will `output`:

```
True
```

---

**Why does this work?**

Well, first take a look at the `documentation` for `len()`:

> Return the length (the number of items) of an object. The argument may be a sequence (such as a string, bytes, tuple, list, or range) or a collection (such as a dictionary, set, or frozen set).

So, to give some examples using `len()`:

```
>>> len("hello")
5
>>> len("fish")
4
>>> len("abc123")
6
>>> len("immutable")
9
```

What the code is doing is comparing whether the `length` of the `string`: `"immutable"` is `equal to` (`==`) `9`. Simple as that!

Hopefully you understand how to do it now!